# MS ACCESS MS SQL ODBC DRIVER MANAGER ERROR

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I am currently working with a **MS ACCESS** front end and database that connects to a **MSSQL** database. This is a closed MDE database that was deployed long before I started working with it and the associated source files appear corrupt.

When I open it on USER1's system it prompts for SQL password and connects flawlessly and is ready to go. When opened on USER2's system it prompts

> "[Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager] Not Found & No Default Driver
>   specified."

Followed by "NO SEC DATA." A different .MDB that connects to the same database works correctly, but it never prompts for User / PW for USER2 either.

I have gone through ODBC settings and have found no difference between the two systems short of the user.

First is it possible that access has cached login info that needs to be cleared since it is not prompting USER2 for SQL Server login information? (However the login it is using works with another access db with similar connections.)

Second is there specifically to look for that would allow one system/user to have connectivity, but another to not with only this file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by locating the table for permissions then reinstalled to OBDC driver.